# How to set connection-timeout in django channel?

Tags: python, django, django-channels, django-channels-presence

Django channels disconnect the client if it doesn't respond for few seconds.
But I can't find where to set that time limit.
i checked [this](https://github.com/django/channels/issues/293) issue.
It says it will be configurable.But I can't find where to set that limit.
thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved this by modifying daphne's code and reinstalling it.

1. Download daphne source code from github
2. Change `ping_interval,ping_timeout` in `server.py` as per your needs.Default is 20,30 (in seconds)
3. Install daphne using `pip install -e /path/to/daphne/(where setup.py is located)`
   Thats all!

`